# Angular 4/Typescript : Httpcode 301 Returned on HTTP GET Request

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, http-status-code-301, angular4-httpclient

I am making HTTP GET on a URL with a querystring parameter. But it is returning Httpcode 301 and the request method is changed to OPTIONS from GET.

```
import { HttpClient ,HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable()
export class PropertyPrefService {  

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configurationService:Configuration) {}

public searchProjects(propFilter:string):any{        
    return this.http.get(this.configurationService.ApiUrl+Filter).subscribe();
}             
}
```

However if I request same URL with javascript simple script as below it gives results as expected.

Comment: HTTP 301 code means the resource has been permanently moved to a new location and you should use the new location's url to access the resource. Can you show what error message you are getting?

Comment: what is Filter in here?

Comment: I am not getting any error message but getting blank response. The URL is valid because if i hit same URL with simple javascript it is returning results.

Comment: Change the code something like: 
public searchProjects(propFilter:string) {        
    return this.http.get(this.configurationService.ApiUrl+Filter);
}     

and use the subscribe method while you call it (from some components)

Comment: I was getting this error when I was making REST calls to an external server(Other than localhost).

Comment: This is nothing to do with the code here, your **web server** is returning a 301, not angular, you need to fix that